# Installation of Jmulti in Ubuntu

Tags: package-management, software-installation, lubuntu

This is my first post in Ask Ubuntu and maybe my question is not "appropriate" for this forum. My problem is I want to install a software in Ubuntu 16 and Lubuntu 17 (I have two computers). The software is compressed and I have read several questions in Ask Ubuntu trying to figure out how to install. But I have failed to install the software is Jmulti (a software for statistical analysis) which is pretty old and haven't been updated since several years ago (maybe 2008). Its download link is

http://www.jmulti.com/download.html

And there is written that " Linux (i386, tested on Suse 9.1 and ubuntu) jmulti_linux-4.15.tgz is still available, but currently newer versions are not ported to Linux anymore due to rather low demand and relatively high efforts, especially for extra testing"

My versions are 64 bits, and this software is i386 (I have never intalled any i386 software in my computers)

It would be great if someone finds out how I can install this software in my computers.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Ubuntu releases are *yy.mm* in format, ie. there were two releases in 2018 being 18.04 LTS (2018.April release) & 18.10 (2018.October) release.  There are no supported releases from 2017, they were not LTS or long-term-support releases so are EOL (17.04 release-upgraded to 17.10, 17.10 to 18.04).  If you are using a Lubuntu from 2017 - it's EOL (end-of-life) & off-topic here, and you should replace it ASAP with a supported release of Lubuntu.

Comment: Yes you can install x86 (32bit) software on x86_64 systems, but the age will be your problem. You'll have to install all dependencies, many of which will be x86 (thus your system will have both installed becoming multiarch). The age of these deps will be your issue. (API/ABI's may have changed & the versions in your release repositories may not be suitable for the old software (opensuse 9.1 was from 2004)

Answer (score 0):

Not going to work on a new Ubuntu system.

But even then: the install of JMulti expects java 5.

I would suggest doing it this way:

1. Current OS. Install virtual box.
2. Install a 32-bit version in virtual box. [xubuntu](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/xubuntu/releases/18.04/release/xubuntu-18.04-desktop-i386.iso) has a 32-bit 18.04 but will be using a newer java (version 8).
3. Install JMulti into that and test if this works work java 8. 
   3b. If not hunt down a very old release of Ubuntu (12.04 32-bit should be possible to find) and install it into that.

If that does not work you will be out of luck.